# How to use @inproceedings ?

Tags: citing

I am new to latex and I want to cite some papers. I have

```
@inproceedings{girshick14CVPR,
    Author = {Girshick, Ross and Donahue, Jeff and Darrell, Trevor and Malik, Jitendra},
    Title = {Rich feature hierarchies for accurate object detection and semantic segmentation},
    Booktitle = {Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
    Year = {2014}
}
```

But I am not sure where to copy paste it. Anyone have any templates ? I tried to search through google.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you already know some LaTeX basics. In the small example below I use the popular and powerful package BibLaTeX.

Put the bibliography entry you gave into a separate file (in the example I call it `ref.bib`. Then you can add a citation using the `\cite{}`command. That also adds the relevant reference to the document if you use the `\printbibliography` command. The option `heading=bibintoc`adds reference list to table of contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Heading}
Some text and a citation \cite{girshick14CVPR}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, you can use the key `girshick14CVPR` to refer to that particular entry. You can change the key as you wish. You can also add additional information to @inproceedings entry, like conference location, date etc. See BibLaTeX documentation (below) for more info about possible fields.

For more information, please read:

https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX

And BibLaTeX documentation:

ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf